# Calling function inside angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, cordova, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs, have creating an phonegap project. In my project I am using WP JSON API User Plus Plugin to fetch data in json format, The API gives the response as few contents, also I need to call another API with parameter get from the previous API. Is it possible to call an API inside an ng-repeat to load different datas.

I am getting data's in json, and load the data in ng-repeat, 
I have tried like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="app in multipleApps" ng-init="getActivationDate(app)">
    <td><h4> {{ app.Name }} </h4></td>
    <td> <img src="{{ app.ava_img }}"/> </td>
</tr>
```

which call the below function,

```
$scope.getActivationDate = function(app) {
  Service.getActivationDate(app.name)
    .then(function(response) {
       var date = response.data.image;  
       $scope.app.ava_img = date;
     },
   // ...
};
```

the output what i am getting is display's the same image for all "app.ava_img", but the response from service is different. please advise regarding the issue but I have no clue how to use it with ng-repeat.

It will be thankful,

Comment: Not a solution to the problem stated, but imo it would be better to already include the img in the initial API call. Now you have to call an API method for each iteration. Reduce the API calls by including the needed data in the initial API call. Then you could access the data needed through `app.img` as you are doing for the name value field. As i'm seeing you are setting `$scope.app.ava_img = date;` while you want to set it only to the method constructor passed object like `app.ava_img = date;`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<tr ng-repeat="app in multipleApps" ng-controller="ItemController">
    <td><h4> {{ app.Name }} </h4></td>
    <td> <img src="{{ app.ava_img }}"/> </td>
</tr>
```

and define a new controller in your app:

```
angular.module("yourapp").controller("ItemController", function($scope, Service){
    Service.getActivationDate($scope.app.name).then(function(response) {
         var date = response.data.image;  
         $scope.app.ava_img = date;
    }
});
```

Then, each iteration of ng-repeat will have its own ItemController instance with different $scope.

Comment: This worked like a dream, I'm working on a retro application and couldn't figure a solution at all, but this is perfect, different scope, but receives the data from the parent scope and able to separate concerns neatly when making separate API calls for each row. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I encourage you to read the docs for [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). 
I assume `app` is an object and `multipleApps` is an array containing those objects.

`$scope.app.ava_img = data;` means you are setting the ava_img property on the app variable on your $scope to the data you have. So assign an array of objects to multipleApps.

Eg: `$scope.multipleApps = [ {name:'a', ava_img:'a.jpg' }, {name: 'b', ava_img: 'b.jpg' } ]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to accomplish but I get the gist of it.

#### ng-init

Firstly, I would avoid using an `ng-init` to call a function.  `ng-init` is usually something I'd use to initialize some trivial value on an object that's specific to helping the UI in some way. The docs even allude to this - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

#### usual way to chain logic together - promises

As somebody who's new to Angular, you've probably encountered promises.  Anytime you're doing something like:

```
someService.getSomething()
.then( function( rsp ){ ... })
.catch( function( err ){...})
```

... you're using the promises API.  As I said earlier, I'm not entirely clear on your application so I will be making some assumptions as I go.

I assume `multipleApps` is the result of either an API call or you're fetching it from a local list?  Let's go with the API call.

```
appService.getApps()
.then( function( rsp ){
    return $scope.multipleApps = rsp.data.data //you structure may differ
})
```

So you're processing the `rsp` in your `then` handler.  All we need to do is chain another series of promises together.  We could iterate through each `app` in the `multipleApps`, then assigning the proper value to the objects on the response, but angular provides us with a better way. Let's use `$q`.  `$q` provides us with the `.all` API. Docs here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all

Here's how I'd use it:

```
appService.getApps()
.then( function( rsp ){

    var multipleApps = rsp.data.data

    var rqsts = []
    for( var app, i = 0; i < multipleApps.length; i++ )
    {
        app = multipleApps[ i ]
        rqsts.push( appService.getActivationDate( app ))
    }

    $q.all( rqsts )
    //this triggers when ALL individual requests have returned
    .then( function( rsps ){

       //rsps is an array of rsp objects from the individual calls above
       for( var iRsp, i = 0; i < rsps.length; i++ )
       {
           iRsps = rsps[ i ]
           multipleApps[ i ].ava_img = iRsps.data.img
       }

       //we're assigning to scope after we've fetched all the data
       $scope.multipleApps = multipleApps
    })
})
```